# Selenium windows don't close

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have some code that opens multiple windows on a chrome webdriver

```
MessageBox.Show(chrome.WindowHandles.Count.ToString());
foreach (var link in _links)
{
    js.ExecuteScript("window.open('" + link.Item1 + "', '" + link.Item2 + "', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=400')");
}
```

on start chrome windowHandles = 1 which is correct.
After the execution of the code above, windowHandles = 50 which is correct.

Now the problem start when I try to close the windows that I opened

```
for (int i = 1; i < chrome.WindowHandles.Count - 1; i++)
{
    chrome.SwitchTo().Window(chrome.WindowHandles[i]).Close();
}
MessageBox.Show(chrome.WindowHandles.Count.ToString());
```

The above code leaves 26 windows open and I don't understand why, can you help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to have a tear down method like this :

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    if (Driver != null)
      Driver.Quit();
}
```

`Quit()` is a **webdriver** command which calls the `driver.dispose` method, which in turn closes all the browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session. If we do not use `quit()` at the end of program, the WebDriver session will not be closed properly and the files will not be cleared off memory. This may result in memory leak errors.

Comment: I do not want tho quit the driver only close the windows, i want to leave one open

Comment: okay can you put some hardcoded sleep before closing ? and see if that helps

Comment: I have, Thread.Sleep(10000);, same problem.

Comment: I see that, the loop you have for closing all the windows starts from 1,  shouldn't it start from 50 or last window handle ? cause Selenium will have focus on the last opened browser window.

Answer (score 0):

As cruisepandey say, reverse does the job. (many tnks)

```
            Parallel.ForEach(_links, link =>
            {
                js.ExecuteScript("window.open('" + link.Item1 + "', '" + link.Item2 + "', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=1000,height=500')");
                HtmlDocument doctab = new HtmlDocument();
                doctab.LoadHtml(chrome.PageSource);
                _docprodutos.Add(doctab);
            });
            _links.Reverse();
            foreach (var janela in _links)
            {
                chrome.SwitchTo().Window(janela.Item2).Close();

            }
```